# How to conditionally set php ini value in .htaccess or through other means for specific requests

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, configuration

I am working with a typical MVC application (happens to be ZF 1.x) making use of mod_rewrite where all requests are routed to a single index.php file in my /public directory.

Both site administrators and general users are dispatched no differently.  Now I am stuck trying to increase some INI values such as `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` (which are PHP_INI_PERDIR changeable) only for the administrative users of the site.

Short of changing how the application is dispatching can anybody suggest an alternative method?  I was looking at the possibility of some sort of conditional block in an .htaccess file perhaps...  Something where the `php_value line is invoked say if the request URI matched a certain pattern.  Pretty sure that is not an option but thought I would ask if anyone had found other solutions.

My options now seem to be increase the values for all users, or rewrite things so that the specific pages needing these increased values are dispatched through a separate directory where I can drop in an alternate .htaccess file.

Comment: Why not increase the value for everyone and check the size with PHP and then let the code run or not depending on if a user has administrator privileges or not?

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  But the main reason for not doing that is the potential of abuse.    If I have to wait for a 500MB file to get uploaded only to reject it. Gives a great vector for attack. You do not want these values that large by default.

Comment: @ficuscr You will always wait for the complete file upload whatever the size of the file, PHP refusing to threath the request doesn't mean Apache won't... Think about that!

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin Point taken.  I suppose that was not the best example.  Take something like `max_input_vars` for example instead.  The gist of what I was saying is still correct I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is not user aware per se, it's a mechanism managed by PHP through the use of cookies, therefore, no, you can't do anything about it except increase the values for everyone!

Comment: I wonder if you could take a step back and "load-balance" your administrative users to a separate httpd/php instance, which would be on the same machine, and use the same database, but run with different settings?

Comment: Is it truly load balancing at this point? And i think it's a bit overkill, you'd have to find a way to identify your users using a cookie or an ipaddress... :)

Comment: Hence my wondering if through httpd and use of htaccess I could make a conditional block matching a URI similar to how a <Files> block works.

Comment: If you place a token in the url, you could use a condition in mod_rewrite but i don't know if it can be done to .htaccess php_value, i doubt it, someone else might have an answer but as far as i know, it can't be done!

Comment: No, it's not true load balancing, but I thought it might be an interesting hack. Some load balancing approaches already divide the load by user (and keep the user session as a whole on a single machine for the duration) so I figured it might not take that much forcing.

Comment: @Matt Gibson, A work around like that I think falls into what I mean by "rewrite things so that the specific pages needing these increased values are dispatched through a separate directory ".  To better explain why I've not done that: The site has no admin section per se, the site basically adds an admin toolbar on certain pages.

Answer (score -1):

Cant you do like (pseudo code)?

```
if($user=='admin') ini_set('upload_max_filesize','100m');
```

Comment: This will not work because upload_max_filesize or post_max_size is evaluated before the script is run!